# First time deploying meteor app with meteor-up

Tags: meteor, web-deployment, shared-hosting, meteor-up, mup

This is the first time i am deploying from Meteor-up and I followed the docs to deploy a dummy application first. I am deploying on a shared linux server. Everything is going great but i can't find my app on ROOT_URL. My domain is pointing to the server and that very domain is also my ROOT_URL. when I hit the domain link it goes to the index of file explorer on the server instead of my web app. I tried to find logs but logs command and --verbose flag returned no log and the command simply run as usual.

Mup version (``1.5.3`):

Mup config

```
{   "servers": {
    "one": {
      "host": "1.2.3.4",
      "username": "totalti1",
      "password": "password",
      "opts": {
        "port": 2083
      }
    }   },   "proxy": {
    "servers": {
      "one": {}
    },
    "domains": "host.com,subdomain.host.com",
    "shared": {
      "httpPort": 80,
      "httpsPort": 443
    }   },   "app": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "path": "../.",
    "deployCheckWaitTime": 300,
    "servers": {
      "one": {}
    },
    "buildOptions": {
      "serverOnly": true
    },
    "env": {
      "ROOT_URL": "https://host.com",
      "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://mongodb:27017/my-app",
      "MONGO_OPLOG_URL": "mongodb://localhost/local",
      "VIRTUAL_HOST": "host.com,subdomain.host.com",
      "HTTPS_METHOD": "noredirect",
      "VIRTUAL_PORT": 3000,
      "HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT": 1
    },
    "docker": {
      "image": "abernix/meteord:node-12-base",
      "prepareBundle": false,
      "stopAppDuringPrepareBundle": true,
      "imagePort": 3000,
      "args": [
        "--link=mongodb:mongodb"
      ]
    },
    "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
    "type": "meteor"   },   "mongo": {
    "version": "3.4.1",
    "servers": {
      "one": {}
    },
    "dbName": "DemoApp"   } }
```

the port of my host is 2083 and I am not sure if that is causing a problem. I am not sure if the deployment was unsuccessful or the URL had a mistake. I was able to get some log after setting the debug Environmental variable. And here is it.
Output of command

```
$ DEBUG=mup* mup reconfig --verbose   
mup:updates checking for updates +0ms   
mup:updates Packages:  [ { name: 'mup', path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/mup/package.json' } ] +2ms   
mup:updates retrieving tags for mup +2ms   
mup:api Running command default.reconfig +0ms   
mup:module:default exec => mup reconfig +0ms  
mup:api Running command meteor.envconfig +2ms   
mup:module:meteor exec => mup meteor envconfig +0ms

Started TaskList: Configuring App [213.136.76.119] - Pushing the Startup Script   
mup:updates finished update check for mup +1s
```

I am looking for some instant help as i am stuck on this deployment for three days now. Thanks in Advance

***EDIT***

Is there a way to know that the deployment was successful or not. Also is there something wrong with my ROOT_URL? Root url contains the IP of server on which i have hosted the app. The domain also points to the IP. When I access by IP it says

```
Sorry!
IP changed or server misconfig or site may have moved to different ip. Contact your hosting provider.
```

When i access via domain it shows the empty directory the default domain is set to.

Comment: If you want it to work with https you need to configure the [reverse proxy](https://meteor-up.com/docs.html#ssl)

Comment: @Jankapunkt What does the output of reconfig command says. was the deployment successful?

Comment: and just to be sure, you *did* run `mup deploy` as well, right?

Comment: Yes the reconfig comes after `mup deploy`

Comment: Are you using the public ip address for the DNS entries?